# In MongoDB how can I sort documents based on a property in an embedded object?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

In my products collection, I can find all products that have been released in the region 'GB':

```
> db.products.find({'release.region':'GB'}).pretty();

{
        "_id" : "foo",
        "release" : [
                {
                        "region" : "GB",
                        "date" : ISODate("2012-03-01T00:00:00Z")
                },
                {
                        "region" : "US",
                        "date" : ISODate("2012-09-01T00:00:00Z")
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "bar",
        "release" : [
                {
                        "region" : "FR",
                        "date" : ISODate("2010-07-01T00:00:00Z")
                },
                {
                        "region" : "GB",
                        "date" : ISODate("2012-05-01T00:00:00Z")
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "baz",
        "release" : [
                {
                        "region" : "GB",
                        "date" : ISODate("2011-05-01T00:00:00Z")
                },
                {
                        "region" : "NZ",
                        "date" : ISODate("2012-02-01T00:00:00Z")
                }
        ]
}
```

How can I sort the results in ascending date order, using the GB release date? (e.g. the order should be baz, foo, bar)

Note, I cannot do the sorting on the client side.

Alternatively, how can I better organise the data to make this possible.

Edit: I changed the FR release date for 'bar' to illustrate that vivek's solution is not correct.

Comment: Do you need the `release` elements from the regions besides "GB" in the sorted results?

Comment: No they are not needed. I tried removing them with an $elemMatch projection, but this doesn't affect the sort which is applied before  the projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't need the `release` elements besides the ones from the "GB" region, you can do it with `aggregate` like this:

```js
db.products.aggregate(
    // Filter the docs to just those containing the 'GB' region
    { $match: {'release.region': 'GB'}},
    // Duplicate the docs, one per release element
    { $unwind: '$release'},
    // Filter the resulting docs to just include the ones from the 'GB' region
    { $match: {'release.region': 'GB'}},
    // Sort by release date
    { $sort: {'release.date': 1}})
```

output:

```js
{
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": "baz",
      "release": {
        "region": "GB",
        "date": ISODate("20110501T00:00:00Z")
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "foo",
      "release": {
        "region": "GB",
        "date": ISODate("20120301T00:00:00Z")
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "bar",
      "release": {
        "region": "GB",
        "date": ISODate("20120501T00:00:00Z")
      }
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

Comment: It looks like that does what I need. Do you know how this impacts performance, if for example there are 10,000 products, and some products may have hundreds of items in the 'release' array?

Comment: @nick `aggregate` is pretty efficient, but only testing can give you your answer.