# Loop doesn't work in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I wrote script for search anagrams in my Mongo database:

```
print("Search anagrams");

var input = db.dbName.find();
var i = 0;

input.forEach(function(word) {
    var j = 0;
    var alphabetical = word.name.split("").sort().join("");

    input.forEach(function(worter) {
        if (i != j) {
            if (alphabetical == worter.name.split("").sort().join("")) {
                print(word.name + " : " + worter + " - " + i + ", " + j);
            }
        }
        j++;
    });
    i++;
});
```

but the first loop doesn't work. Do you have any idea why? Sample record from db:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5491d807dacc815b3043ae24"), "name" : "monki" }
```

Comment: you could transform the cursor to an array: `var input = db.dbName.find().toArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.dbName.find()
```

return cursor. It is not array. You iterate through cursor two times (outer loop and inner loop), and this may be a problem. Check if this work

```
input.forEach(function(word) {
 console.log(word);
}
```

Comment: yes - this work. So do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: you have to loop through cursor only once. In your code cursor query db multiple time. To sort check this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/ and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876547/in-mongodb-how-can-i-sort-documents-based-on-a-property-in-an-embedded-object

Comment: maybe add additional field to documents 'sorted_name', and store sorted name (your alphabetical). Then you sort by sorted_name field. It may be faster.